# How to str_extract percentages in R?

Tags: regex, r, string, extract, stringr

From this string `border-color:#002449;left:74.4%top;37%;` I would like to make the first percentage `74.4%` a variable called `X` and the second percentage `37%` a variable called `Y`.

I have tried to play around with this regex `"^.*?(\\d+)%.*"` but this takes out the `%` sign and only extracts the second `4` from `74.4`

Any help will be appreciated. Please let me know if any further information is needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
s <- "border-color:#002449;left:74.4%top;37%;"
regmatches(s, gregexpr("\\d+(\\.\\d+){0,1}%", s))[[1]]
# [1] "74.4%" "37%"
```

or

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(s, "\\d+(\\.\\d+){0,1}%")[[1]]
# [1] "74.4%" "37%"
```

Comment: Two variants: `'\\d+\\.?\\d*%'` (equivalent) and `'[\\d.]+%'` (works here, but less specific about periods)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am currently doing: `X <- str_extract(s, "\\d+(\\.\\d+){0,1}%")` and this will extract the first percentage. I'm sure there is only a small change needed  to only extract the second percentage so that I may create the `Y` variable, but I am not sure what it is.

Comment: @Dre, if you really want to have two separate variables, why not to extract the two strings as in my answer to some variable `e` and then `X <- e[1]; Y <- e[2]`? I don't think there is some change to achieve what you want with `str_extract`; it returns the first part of `s` that matches the pattern (which cannot include information about relative position in `s`).