# Create subset with %like% operator

Tags: r, regex, for-loop, data.table, rlike

I'm looking for some help to create subsets using `%like%` operator in **R**.

I have a table called 'pruebas1', which contains this information:

```
      scenario_name | land_consumption | land_consumption_pct
ContenciÃ³n al 30%      692.00              11.081468525813
ContenciÃ³n al 50%      221.23               3.542703786613
ContenciÃ³n al 70%       94.98               1.520975451494
ContenciÃ³n al 95%       69.29               1.109583760966
```

And more rows. They share a pattern, the percentage value '30%', '50%'

I want to create a subset for each percentage value, and I tried to do it with this code:

```
for (i in 1:33){
  if (prueba1$scenario_name %like% '%30%'){
    esc_30[[i]]<-prueba1$scenario_name[[i]]
  }
}
```

The result is an object with no data. I built this with a friend and we are new to this. As you can see we need help first to use correctly the `%like%` operator and of course make a loop to create a subset for the different percentages values.

You can help us with specific links or help with the code directly.

Comment: I'm adding the data.table tag since that's the only place I've seen %like%. Feel free to revert the edit and clarify if using something else.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35822899/how-to-str-extract-percentages-in-r

Comment: `like` uses a patter passed to `grepl`, so when you use a pattern of `'%30%'`, the percent sign is an unescaped delimiter.  Try changing it to `'30\\%'`.  The `like` is also vectorized, so the first element determines if the `if` evaluates to `TRUE` or `FALSE`.  Perhaps what you want to do is `esc_30[prueba1$scenario_name %like% '30\\%'] <- prueba1$scenario_name[prueba1$scenario_name %like% '30\\%']`

Comment: Sounds like you just want `split(pruebas, pruebas$scenario_name)`, or do you have different strings that contain `30%` that you want grouped together?

Comment: @KerryJackson  I used your code and that create a list which has the total number of rows, but only rows with '30\\%' have data. Instead, I ran a modification of your code `esc_30<- prueba1$scenario_name[prueba1$scenario_name %like% '30\\%']`
And that gives me a list just with the rows that contain '30\\%' - no empty rows-. I want that but with the rest of the columns

Comment: @Gregor yeah, that's what I want

Answer (score 2):

You're probably thinking of the SQL `LIKE` operator, where `x LIKE '%foo%'` means any values that contain `'foo'` in any position.

The equivalent for the data.table `%like%` would be `x %like% ".*foo.*"`. This is because `%like%` works with [regular expressions](https://google.com/search?&q=regular+expression). In a regular expression, the string `.*` means "any character repeated 0, 1 or multiple times".

In R, see `?regex` for how R handles regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid using regexp you should use "fixed" argument in the grepl. The %like% in data.table is a wrapper for grepl.

So, you could try something like:

```
esc30<-prueba1$scenario_name[grepl("30%",prueba1$scenario_name,fixed=T)]
```

If you want to get all the columns:

```
esc30<-prueba1[grepl("30%",prueba1$scenario_name,fixed=T),]
```

However, if you want to not subset items containing "30%" in the middle of the text, you should learn regexps.